# Set xticks interval with date values

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello I have a a list that has about 150 dates that are stored in string format.  I would like to set an interval so that there are only 10 ticks along the x-axis I am not sure how to do this without changing the type format.

```
'1980-06',
'1980-09',
'1980-12',
'1981-03',
'1981-06',
'1981-09',
'1981-12',
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the ticks list you want to show. To get that ticks list, just divide your date list into ten parts and find how far each tick should be. And then use Python's indexing to get the values of ticks. Check below:

```
import math
dates = ['1980-06', '1980-09', '1980-12', '1981-12' ...] # Your date list
date_len = len(dates)
step = int(math.ceil(date_len/10))
ticks = dates[::step] # ticks to show on graph
```